# Is there a way to recover docker volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

Can you recover Docker volume's created by `docker-compose` after running `docker-compose down -v`?

Comment: If you have backups of your data you can. Check [Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I didn't have any volume backup at the moment I deleted my volumes, but I had a host VM snapshot that saved my life. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `docker-compose down -v` will remove all related volumes of that compose. So the answer is can not.

But if you want to create a persistent volume which won't lose data when you down your compose or stop your services, you can map a folder on your machine with a volume inside container, like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
  image: postgres:9.6
  volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

More details here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: Please give me a reason why you downvote my answer.

Comment: I downvote'd - you can [backup, restore or migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes). By default `docker` `volume`'s exist in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`, you can `copy` and `paste` them for a lazy man's backup / restore if you really wanted too. [`docker-compose down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) doesn't delete volumes by default so if you're really going to delete them (e.g. explicitly `docker-compose down -v`) then you should plan a way to recover them.

Comment: Actually we can do that. But I said can not because the question is: **can we recover volumes after we ran `docker-compose down -v`**. And about my suggestion is also work in this case and no need any additional steps. @masseyb

Answer (score -1):

You can create named volumes using

```
docker volume create myvol
```

A named volume is a persistent store on the host machine or remote hosts.

Then get the details of the volumes using

```
docker volume inspect my-vol
```

With compose you can use named volume like this

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
volumes:
  mydata:
```

References
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: Both named and anonymous volumes are removed during a `docker-compose down -v`. Naming the volume doesn't protect it from being removed and doesn't address how to recover the volume.